# I am not sure why I can't open a file

Tags: python, tkinter

I know it's so simple to open a file in Python. However, something is definitely happening here:

```
  File "exercise.py", line 16, in getinput
    f = open('w', fileName)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

Full code, if there might be something wrong with it:

```
from tkinter import *
from os import *

ide = Tk();ide.title("Python 3 IDE")
controls = Tk();controls.title("Controls")

# Variables
tab = False
fileName = 'test.py'

# Get input
textInput = Text(ide)
textInput.pack()

def getinput():
    f = open('w', fileName)
    f.write(textInput.get("1.0", END))
save = Button(controls, text="Save", width=10, height=1, command=getinput).grid(column=0, row=0)
def run():
    system('python3 ' + fileName)
run = Button(controls, text="Run", width=10, height=1, command=run).grid(column=1, row=0)

def tab(arg):
    textInput.insert(INSERT, " " * 4)
    return 'break'
textInput.bind("<Tab>", tab)

# Mainloop
ide.mainloop()
controls.mainloop()
```

PS: i reversed the parameters. Just a mistake.

Comment: Filename *then* mode !

Comment: Wait... it still does not work paxdiablo

Comment: read the doc about `open()` and use a context manager `with`

Comment: You're replacing `open` with `os.open` by importing everything from `os`. Probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks, deceze apparently got it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your import statement which says `from os import *`, which means you're importing everything from `os` and doesn't need to suffix it with `os` and now it replaces the inbuilt `open()` function of python. So `os.open()` replaces `open()`.  Change the import statement to:

```
import os
```

and then

```
os.system('python3 ' + fileName)
```

This is probably one of the good reason why one shouldn't use `from x import *`.

Comment: Belated thanks... I guess

Answer (score 1):

You're right, something is happening, but not as you intend. Reverse the order of the inputs

```py
f = open(fileName, 'w') # do this, or
f = open(fileName, mode='w')
```

Though I would suggest you try to use the python idiom

```py
with open(fileName, mode='w') as f:
    ...
```

as this will inevitably save you headache in the future.

Comment: I know this was really kind of you, but it says another error: TypeError: open() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)

Comment: `os.open` replaces the default `open()` because of the import style of the OP

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the parameter on the open method :

```
f = open(FILENAME , "w" )
```

Should fix it